# Where does the 'method' implementation go? (I'm a newbie)

Tags: objective-c

I have this code:

```
#import "SQLiteDB.h"

@implementation SQLiteDB

@synthesize db, dbPath, databaseKey;

@end



//--------------    check for database or create it    ----------------|

- (void)checkForDatabase  {

    NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *databasePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] 
                              stringByAppendingString:@"/ppcipher.s3db"];

    if(![filemanager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]) {  //Database doesn't exist yet, so we create it...
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/ppcipher.s3db"];

        sqlite3 *db;
        if(sqlite3_open(databasePath, db) == SQLITE_OK)  {

        }

    }
}
```

It's complaining that "method definition not in @implementation context".  So where does it go?  (I tried in the .h file, but still get the error)

Comment: Dude -- go read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method implementation must occur between the `@implementation` and the `@end`. That is:

```
#import "SQLiteDB.h"

@implementation SQLiteDB

@synthesize db, dbPath, databaseKey;

-(void) checkForDatabase {

    ...

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be inside @implementation block

```
#import "SQLiteDB.h"

@implementation SQLiteDB

@synthesize db, dbPath, databaseKey;



//--------------    check for database or create it    ----------------|

- (void)checkForDatabase  {

    NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *databasePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] 
                              stringByAppendingString:@"/ppcipher.s3db"];

    if(![filemanager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]) {  //Database doesn't exist yet, so we create it...
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/ppcipher.s3db"];

        sqlite3 *db;
        if(sqlite3_open(databasePath, db) == SQLITE_OK)  {

        }

    }
}

@end
```